# Parse - cannot retrieve objects with parse query(findinBackground)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to get simple string object from parse table, and not able to do it. I followed parse documentation and still can't understand why i get nothing back in my query.
There is no exception in logcat and the 'else' part is not triggered.
I do able to insert some objects to the table. 
does anyone find something wrong with the code?  thanks.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Main");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                Facts = new String[parseObjects.size()-1][3];
                int index=0;
                String Text = "";
                for(int i=0;i<parseObjects.size();i++){
                    Text = parseObjects.get(i).getString("ColumnName");
                    if (i < Facts.length){
                        Facts[index][0] = Text;
                        index ++;
                    }
                }
                //index = 0;
            }
            else {

                Log.d("App", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

http://postimg.org/image/gg30qltob/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the database it would be useful for debugging.

Comment: Sorry, i was not able to put the SS directly here, so i added a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code modify the loop to this.

```
String text;
String facts[][] = new String[parseObjects.size()][1];
int i=0;
for(ParseObject po : parseObjects){
     text = po.getString("ColumnName");
     facts[i][0]=text;    
     i++;            
}
```

Comment: did you change **Text** to **text**? and i modified the code a little bit now

Comment: Check the logcat for any exceptions debug the app using breakpoints

Comment: well, did it.. there are no exceptions inside this block. the only exception i get is when i'm trying to do something with the array, and its null - becasue the block is not triggered.

Comment: is there any chance that its not working because i'm triggering the queries from the activity, but the code itself is in different class that responsible for the Parse connection? (i believe not, because i'm able to insert objects with functions that implemented there)

Comment: No that's not the problem. Make 'parseObjects' final. Remove storing into fact instead just show the text as a toast to user take a look at my modified code tell whether it displays something.

Comment: now with toast i can see the objects i'm trying to retrieve. i guess that the problem is that - inside the "done" block i can see the objects,but in the moment its over, the "facts" array is becoming empty again. is there any option to save the changes after this code block? i've already tried with global fields, and different function in the same class.

Comment: its not working like that, i've already tried that. in the moment the "done" function ends, the array becoming empty again, and i cant return it from this function

Comment: Dude there are some changes **make the array global** and use **parseObjects.size()** not **parseObjects.size()-1**

Comment: The array is already global, like i said, already tried that option.

Comment: Dude try changing variables to small letters and use the array size I provided.

Comment: Hi, well as i said few times already - everything you offered was already tried, thanks anyway.

Comment: Tell me your keys I will try out and tell you.

Comment: Tried now I get the output with my code posted above

Comment: you get the output, and you can pass the output to different functions/classes? i'm also getting the output, but this is no the issue

Comment: If you are getting output and only passing is wrong mark this question and create a new one. This question is solved according to the title.